# Traversal In linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am new to linked list..My simple code is to create linked list and insert nodes at the end and traverse it..
 My problems are-
 1)-Every time insert function is called,head pointer gets null
2)-not working right while going in show function..

Please help..Thanks in advance

```
#include<iostream>
#include<malloc.h>
using namespace std;

struct linkedList
{
    int value;
    linkedList *next;
};
linkedList* head = NULL;
void insert(linkedList* head, int data)
{

    linkedList *ptr;
    linkedList *node;
    node = (linkedList*) malloc(sizeof(struct linkedList));
    node->value = data;
    node->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL)
    {

        head = node;

    }
    else
    {
        ptr = head;
        while (ptr != NULL)
        {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        ptr = node;
    }
}
void show(struct linkedList *head)
{

    struct linkedList *ptr;
    ptr = head;

    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        cout << ptr->value << endl;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}
int main()
{

    int size = 5;

    int array[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter value" << endl;
        cin >> array[i];

        insert(head, array[i]);
    }

    show(head);

}
```

Comment: Learn about the difference between passing arguments *by value* and *by reference*.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Looks like you're learning `C` instead of `C++`.  What's that `malloc` doing there (instead of `new`)?

Comment: @JoachiPileborg can you write the code please..that would me a real help

Comment: [Find a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), it will tell you all you need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `insert()` function:

- when `head` is NULL, you are assigning the new node to the local `head` parameter, which is not updating the caller's `head` variable.  That is why your global `head` variable is always NULL.  This is because you are passing the `head` parameter **by value**, so you are assigning the new node to a *copy*, not the original.  You need to pass the parameter **by reference/pointer** instead.
- when `head` is not NULL, you are not traversing the nodes correctly to find the tail node, so `ptr` is always NULL after the traversal.  You are not setting the `next` field of the tail node at all.

Also, your `main()` is leaking the allocated nodes.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>

struct linkedNode
{
    int value;
    linkedNode *next;
};

void insertValue(linkedNode* &head, int data)
{
    linkedNode *node = new linkedNode;
    node->value = data;
    node->next = NULL;

    if (!head)
    {
        head = node;
    }
    else
    {
        linkedNode *ptr = head;
        while (ptr->next)
        {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        ptr->next = node;
    }
}

void showValues(linkedNode *head)
{
    linkedNode *ptr = head;
    while (ptr)
    {
        std::cout << ptr->value << std::endl;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

void freeValues(linkedNode* &head)
{
    linkedNode *ptr = head;
    head = NULL;

    while (ptr)
    {
        linkedNode *next = ptr->next;
        delete ptr;
        ptr = next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    linkedNode* mylist = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter value" << std::endl;

        int value;
        if (std::cin >> value)
            insertValue(mylist, value);
    }

    showValues(mylist);
    freeValues(mylist);

    return 0;
}
```

That being said, if you keep track of the tail node in the list, inserts at the end would be much faster and efficient since you would not need to traverse the list at all:

```
#include <iostream>

struct linkedNode
{
    int value;
    linkedNode *next;

    linkedNode(int data)
        value(data), next(NULL)
    {
    }
};

struct linkedList
{
    linkedNode *head;
    linkedNode *tail;

    linkedList()
        : head(NULL), tail(NULL)
    {
    }

    ~linkedList()
    {
        linkedNode *ptr = head;
        while (ptr)
        {
            linkedNode *next = ptr->next;
            delete ptr;
            ptr = next;
        }
    }

    void insert(int data)
    {
        linkedNode *node = new linkedNode(data);

        if (!head)
            head = node;

        if (tail)
            tail->next = node;
        tail = node;
    }

    void showValues()
    {
        linkedNode *ptr = head;
        while (ptr)
        {
            std::cout << ptr->value << std::endl;
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    linkedList mylist;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter value" << std::endl;

        int value;
        if (std::cin >> value)
            mylist.insert(value);
    }

    mylist.showValues();

    return 0;
}
```

In which case, you could just throw all of this away and use the standard [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) class instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

void showValue(int value)
{
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}

void showValues(const std::list<int> &values)
{
    std::for_each(values.begin(), values.end(), showValue);

    /* or, if you are using C++11:

    std::for_each(values.begin(), values.end(),
        [](int value){ std::cout << value << std::endl; }
    );
    */
}

int main()
{
    std::list<int> mylist;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter value" << std::endl;

        int value;
        if (std::cin >> value)
            mylist.push_back(value);
    }

    showValues(mylist);

    return 0;
}
```